# How to embed audio in Slack via API?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-block-kit

We want to be able to embed an audio file in a Slack chat via the web API.
So far I managed to `files.remote.add` but that's just an external link.
Then I tried `files.upload` and share it to a channel, it does embed and play right inside Slack, but for us it's a suboptimal solution, as users can easily download the file, which is against our requirements.
Is there another way to achieve this?

*PS: I've read almost all the documentation, there doesn't seem to be an audio or media block type, although I've seen examples that cite a `file` block type which is neither documented in the API and it's not defined in Bolt. (at least there are no type definitions for it for typescript)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to embed a media player (audio or video) via the API. We're constantly tuning our APIs, if you have a specific use case in mind, would you mind writing in to feedback@slack.com and we'll get it logged. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much, I did write.